# How to push to array inside dynamic object using React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, immutability

In this small code that I've written I have created a dynamic object upon setting state and adding files to it. However, the new file overwrites the previous file. With no luck, I have tried using the spread operator inside the array brackets next to `mappedFiles`. It seems upon setting the state dynamically, I am not able to concatenate or push to the array inside the `files object`.

Here is the code...

```
import React, { useCallback, useState, useContext } from "react";
import { ImageUploadContext } from "../../Store";
import styles from "./commentssection.module.css";
import { useDropzone } from "react-dropzone";

function ImageUploader({ title }) {
  const [files, setFiles] = useContext(ImageUploadContext);
  const maxSize = 5048576;


 //ISSUE IS HERE. CREATING THE SETSTATE INSIDE THIS CALLBACK
  const onDrop = useCallback(
    (acceptedFiles) => {
      const mappedFiles = acceptedFiles.map((file) =>
        Object.assign(file, {
          preview: URL.createObjectURL(file),
        })
      );
      // This setstate function adds to dynamic array but doesn't return previous one. The array is being overwritten
      setFiles((state) => ({ ...state, [title]: [mappedFiles] }));
    },
    [files]
  );

  const {
    isDragActive,
    getRootProps,
    getInputProps,
    isDragReject,
    acceptedFiles,
    rejectedFiles,
  } = useDropzone({
    onDrop,
    accept: "image/*",
    minSize: 0,
    maxSize: 10000000,
  });
  console.log(files);
  const isFileTooLarge = rejectedFiles
    ? rejectedFiles.length > 0 && rejectedFiles[0].size > maxSize
    : null;
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Please include comments in notes</p>
      <hr className={styles["HR"]} />
      <form className={styles["UploadForm"]}>
        <div className={styles["UploadWrapper"]}>
          <h5>Upload photos of issues found in the {title}</h5>
          <section className={styles["Container"]}>
            <div className={styles["ImageInput"]} {...getRootProps()}>
              <input {...getInputProps()} />
              {!isDragActive && "Click here or drop a file to upload!"}
              {isDragActive && !isDragReject && "Drop it like it's hot!"}
              {isDragReject && "File type not accepted, sorry!"}
              {isFileTooLarge && (
                <div className="text-danger mt-2">File is too large.</div>
              )}
            </div>
          </section>
          <div>
            {files[title]
              ? files[title].map((object, index) =>
                  object.map((subObject, subIndex) => {
                    return (
                      <img
                        style={{ height: "80px" }}
                        className={styles["RenderedImage"]}
                        key={index}
                        src={subObject.preview}
                      />
                    );
                  })
                )
              : null}
          </div>
          <p>
            Please take a picture of any issues that you find and upload them
            here. NOTE: it is only necessary to upload pictures of problems that
            you find.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className={styles["CommentWrapper"]}>
          <h5>Notes of the {title}</h5>
          <textarea className={styles["Textarea"]} />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
export default ImageUploader;
```

**Edit:**

I was able to figure it out thanks to [@lawrence-witt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63331375/12965111)[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63331375/12965111) . Here is the code for the arrays to be parent component specific.

```
const onDrop = useCallback(
    (acceptedFiles) => {
      const mappedFiles = acceptedFiles.map((file) =>
        Object.assign(file, {
          preview: URL.createObjectURL(file),
        })
      );
      return files[title]
        ? setFiles((state) => ({
            ...state,
            [title]: [...state[title], mappedFiles],
          }))
        : setFiles((state) => ({
            ...state,
            [title]: [mappedFiles],
          }));
    },
    [files, title]
  );
```

Comment: try doing this setFiles({ ...file, [title]: [mappedFiles] });

Comment: Same result as before

Comment: What does `ImageUploadContext` look like?

Comment: It's an empty object. Ex. `useState({})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I spotted the issue - you need to include `title` in the dependency array of `onDrop`:

```
const onDrop = useCallback(
    (acceptedFiles) => {
      ...
    },
    [files, title]
);
```

Otherwise you run the risk of having a stale value for `title` which would overwrite your state object's property.

Edit:

I think this is what you were looking for:

```
setFiles((state) => ({ ...state, [title]: [...state[title], ...mappedFiles]}));
```

Comment: That didn't fix it. The issue is whether or not the array state inside the object not being returned along with the new value. Therefore, this setState is overriding the state. The title is consistently returning and read.

Comment: You are using a new value for title every time you set the state right?

Comment: No, the title works as expected. It's being passed down from the parent.

Comment: You can't have two identical keys on the same object. If `title` does not change then this is the expected behaviour. Perhaps you want `files` to be an array, and each callback invocation to create a new object in it?

Comment: I could do that. However, I would like it to be component specific to where I can access it. If I put it as an array, then any component would have access to it without a specific key. What I mean is I'm trying to have it organized so that each parent that uses this component has a key to a part it can access and render the images in that component. Hopefully, I explained it well...

Comment: Do you want all newly mapped files to be inside the same array for that title?

Comment: Yes, I would like it to be in the same array. That will help it be parent component specific

Comment: It gives an error `Uncaught TypeError: state[title] is not iterable` due to the fact that `[title]` isn't set in the state at the start. It doesn't know what to copy. I will add a ternary `setFiles()` to see if that works

Answer (score 0):

If your state object with array looks like below

```
var std={students:{names:["AAA","BBB","CCC"]}}
```

State

```
const[students,setstudents]=useState(std)
```

setState

```
 setstudents({ ...students, ...students.names.push("DDD") })
```